# Mapping dynamic elements with @FindBy annotations and PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

For the Page Object example class below, I have an accountsLink private member which maps to a non-dynamic element on the Login page when it loads. It is initialized using the FindBy annotation when the initElements method is called from the constructor.

```
public class Login {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id = "account")
    private WebElement accountsLink;

    //constructor, elements are initialized by the PageFactory
    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //clicking accounts opens a dynamic ajax menu which has a Sign In Button
    public SignInPage clickAccountsLink() {
        accountsLink.click();   
        WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signin"));
        signInButton.click();
        return new SignInPage(driver);
    }
}
```

Now for the problem. I have another element (signInButton) which is dynamically loaded only when you click the accountsLink element. This action doesn't take you to another page but only brings up an ajax menu where the sign in button will appear.

My question is, since the signInButton element only appears when the accountsLink element is clicked, can it be declared as a member of the Login class with a FindBy annotation or do I have to stick with my current solution of using a driver.findElement(By.id("signin")) inside the clickAccountsLink method?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I avoid the use of `PageFactory` altogether. You end up with a mix of annotated elements and scraping the page as needed. I prefer to scrape the page as needed all the time for consistency and for performance.

Comment: It makes sense though in a purely static webpage, but hardly any websites today are considered static. So you are right.

Answer (score 1):

When `PageFactory.initElements` is called it parses the current DOM. If the `WebElement` doesn't exist in that time it can't be given as a value to a variable, exactly as you can't locate non-existing `WebElement` using `driver.findElement`.

Your solution is the way to go, although I would use [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and  [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) when loading the `signInButton`.

Comment: I wrote the class to provide a quick example. But I will definitely use the explicit wait and Expected Conditions when writing my actual code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare, I don't think it's gonna give you any error. Page Factory creates a dummy element when it initialized the class. It creates the actual element only when you intersect with the element for the first time.

For example in following class **NoExistingElement** element doesn't exist and it won't give me any error, If I will call the **enterText** method of class. The test case will pass without any error.

However, If i will try to call any function on **NoExistingElement** element then only it will fail with Webdriver exception, ElementNotFoundException

```
   public class GoogleSearch {

    @FindBy(name="q")
    static WebElement searchBox;

    @FindBy(name = "qqqqq")
    WebElement NoExistingElement;

    public GoogleSearch(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }

    public void searchOnGoogle(String text){
        searchBox.sendKeys(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: I see. But in the case that the NoExistingElement actually exists, can I just call PageFactory.initElements again to initialize? The downside and (performance impact) is that it will reinitialize those elements that are already found when calling the initElements the first time.

Comment: @jeffsia as I said it doesn't intitilize the object with actual value, it's like lazy initialization, actual value gets populated only when you do some action for the first time. i.e. in out case when `searchBox.sendKeys(text);` when this is called at that time `searchBox` is populated.  Hope it's clear now.

Comment: if that is what indeed happens, the why call PageFactory.initElements() at all?

Comment: it's the method which creates the the object of the class and initialize your web element with proxy (dummy)